# Elasticsearch Parse Exception error when attempting to index PDF

Tags: pdf, base64, elasticsearch, apache-tika, osx-server

I'm just getting started with elasticsearch. Our requirement has us needing to index thousands of PDF files and I'm having a hard time getting just ONE of them to index successfully.

Installed the Attachment Type plugin and got response: `Installed mapper-attachments`.

Followed the [Attachment Type in Action tutorial](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/07/18/attachment-type-in-action.html) but the process hangs and **I don't know how to interpret the error message**. Also tried the [gist](https://gist.github.com/1075067) which hangs in the same place.

```
$ curl -X POST "localhost:9200/test/attachment/" -d json.file 
{"error":"ElasticSearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from (offset=0, length=9): [106, 115, 111, 110, 46, 102, 105, 108, 101]]","status":400}
```

More details:

The `json.file` contains an embedded Base64 PDF file (as per instructions). The first line of the file *appears* correct (to me anyway): `{"file":"JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjE1OCAwIG9iaiA8`...

I'm not sure if maybe the `json.file` is invalid or if maybe elasticsearch just isn't set up to parse PDFs properly?!?

**Encoding** - Here's how we're encoding the PDF into `json.file` (as per tutorial):

```
coded=`cat fn6742.pdf | perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'print encode_base64($_)'`
json="{\"file\":\"${coded}\"}"
echo "$json" > json.file
```

also tried:

```
coded=`openssl base64 -in fn6742.pdf
```

log:

```
[2012-06-07 12:32:16,742][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Bailey, Paul] [test][0], node[AHLHFKBWSsuPnTIRVhNcuw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [index {[test][attachment][DauMB-vtTIaYGyKD4P8Y_w], source[json.file]}]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchParseException: Failed to derive xcontent from (offset=0, length=9): [106, 115, 111, 110, 46, 102, 105, 108, 101]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.xContent(XContentFactory.java:147)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.createParser(XContentHelper.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:451)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:437)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:210)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:532)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Hoping someone can help me see what I'm missing or did wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following error points to the source of the problem.

```
Failed to derive xcontent from (offset=0, length=9): [106, 115, 111, 110, 46, 102, 105, 108, 101]
```

The UTF-8 codes [106, 115, 111, ...] show that you are trying to index string "json.file" instead of content of the file.

To index content of the file simply add letter "@" in front of the file name.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/test/attachment/" -d @json.file
```

Comment: Ah, you are correct! Thanks for your help! But, now I've tried adding the `@` in front of filename and it just hangs with no output to the log?!?  I need to *ctrl-C* to get my shell back. Any ideas? Maybe a way to make log more helpful?

Comment: Could you run jstack and see where it hangs?

Comment: The needle in the haystack!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's necessary to `export ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true` before running a java app on a 'headless' server... who would'a thought!?!

Comment: it's worth noting that this only silences the error. @imotov's answer is probably the correct answer for this problem. Another reason a `Failed to derive xcontent` error will pop up is when an empty payload is passed into elastic.