# Unable to insert a record into ElasticSearch using node.js http.request - MapperParsingException[failed to parse]

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, http, elasticsearch

Trying to insert a record into ElasticSearch using node.js's **http** module  (***not*** using 3rd party modules)

**Setup**: running instance of ElasticSearch locally on port **9200** (default)

Node.js Code:

```
var querystring = require('querystring'); // to build our post string
var http = require('http');

// Build the post string from an object
var data = querystring.stringify({
  "text" :"hello world"
});

// An object of options to indicate where to post to
var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '9200',
    path: '/twitter/tweets/1',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
};

// Set up the request
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
    });
});

// post the data
post_req.write(data);
post_req.end();
```

I get the following **Error**:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: 
ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent 
from (offset=0, length=18): [116, 101, 120, 116, 61, 104, 
101, 108, 108, 111, 37, 50, 48, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]]; ",
"status":400}
```

But doing the following **CURL**s works as expected:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{"message" : "hello world"}'
```

I Looked at the following StackOverflow questions which have similar error messages:

- [Getting error mapper parsing exception while indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707072/getting-error-mapper-parsing-exception-while-indexing)
- [Elasticsearch Parse Exception error when attempting to index PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017543/elasticsearch-parse-exception-error-when-attempting-to-index-pdf)
- [ElasticSearch Error: MapperParsingException failed to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355553/elasticsearch-error-mapperparsingexception-failed-to-parse)

Neither of these answered my question.

*Any* help much appreciated. ***Thanks***!

**Note**: I am *deliberately* trying to use the ElasticSearch REST API using ***only Node.js Core*** (*no 3rd party*) modules (please don't suggest using **elasticsearch-js** or **es** or **request**, etc )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its *obvious* in retrospect.
Using the **querystring** module was the mistake.
ElasticSearch *expects* the data to be sent as JSON ("Stringified")

so code needs to be:

```
var http = require('http');

// ElasticSearch Expects JSON not Querystring!
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "text" :"everything is awesome"
});

// An object of options to indicate where to post to
var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '9200',
    path: '/twitter/tweets/1234',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
};

// Set up the request
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
    });
});

// post the data
post_req.write(data);
post_req.end();
```

This *works as expected*. Confirmed using:

```
curl -GET http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweets/1234?pretty
```

(***Thanks @FelipeAlmeida*** for helping me realise this)

Comment: For anyone reading this the curl example at the end is missing an 's' on the end of 'tweet' as part of the URL

Comment: Thanks @jtromans I've fixed the typo. Stoked it was useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Although it may be possible to index data on Elasticsearch using formencoding (I'm not sure, I would have to research that), the way 99% talk to Elasticsearch is via pure JSON requests.

So try changing `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to `'Content-type': 'application/json'` and tell me if it's worked.

Comment: I should have given the *full* list of things I tried before posting this question. changing the **Content-Type** to `'application/json'` was one of the. sadly it does not fix it. :-(

Comment: Changing content-type to application/json was half the answer. The most important part was sending the data as JSON... I was url-encoding the data instead of doing a JSON.stringify() - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ok then. Happy to have helped =)